# Visual Studio 2019 for mac does not have WCF Service Application Template

Tags: asp.net, macos, visual-studio, wcf

[I am trying to create a project with WCF server application template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0nyK.png)

The above is a screenshot of project creation phase. Can anyone let me know where to find it ?

Answer (score 1):

VS2019 for Mac version does not have .Net Framework web application.
Maybe you can use gRPC Service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/why-grpc 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-mac